# Are press releases copyrighted?

Tags: copyright

Many companies have a press release section on their websites called newsroom or another similar term, and some even title it "for the journalists".

Does that mean those press releases and their multimedia attachments can be republished?

Answer (score 3):

Anything that somebody writes is copyrighted, even if you call it a "press release". That means that nobody can copy it without permission. If you hand it out to a bunch of people and write "press release", the only reasonable interpretation of the designation "press release" is that you are granting permission to copy (as well as paraphrase).

Comment: re: "anything that somebody writes is copyrighted" is patently untrue.  It is only copyrighted if the law says it is.  [17 U.S. Code § 105](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/105) explicitly makes any writing that is work of a Federal officer or employee, as part of their official duties, exempt from copyright protection.  This is relevant to this question because governments do like to issue press releases.

Comment: "any writing that is work of a Federal officer or employee, as part of their official duties, exempt from copyright protection"... within the jurisdiction of US law. Has that ever been challenged internationally?

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd this is the current US copyright law.  Are you asking if anyone tried to challenge applicability of the US copyright law to the US federal government employees?

Comment: Thanks for your answers.  I know that US government workers' writings are public domain works,  (but some don't give a clarification - example, in the case of Smithsonian museum's web text, they never clarify if they are public domain or not... )

Comment: @grovkin No, I'm wondering whether for any reason anybody has challenged the applicability of the US federal exemption in the broader international context. For example, the US Federal Government seeks to retain copyright if valuable material it has compiled is printed and bound by an unscrupulous offshore publisher, or a well-meaning advocacy group demands that a researcher's copyright be respected since the US position is contrary to international conventions.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd a 3rd party wouldn't have standing.  Because the exemption is for Federal employees, their work product is intellectual property of the Federal government.  So this has the effect of the Federal government giving away the IP which it creates.

Comment: @grovkin That might not be recognised outside US jurisdiction.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd what are you talking about?  What's not going to be recognized?  That the federal employees work for the federal government?  This would be an interesting twist. Or that Employers own the IP produced, *as work product*, by their employees?  The latter is just the law as it applies to all employers.. not the just the government.  Or is someone planning to argue that work product is not owned by employers?  They would be just changing the definition of what an employer is.

Comment: @grovkin read the question I asked. If you want to say that it has not, do so. If you don't understand what I'm asking, say nothing.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd well, it sounds to me like you challenged it... here in this comment thread; just not in any legal forum or in any way that any legal forum accept.  I tried to explain why this wouldn't be seriously considered by any legal establishment.  I am sorry if it's curt.  I should have taken care to be more polite about it.  But any attempts to challenge this in a court would fail for the reasons already stated.

Comment: @grovkin Look, I appreciate the fact that you posted a link to US law: I was aware of the provisions but it's always good to have something definitive; BUT Titl 17 was promulgated in 1947 which was before the USA reluctantly ratified the Berne Convention (1988/9) which must be recognised as modifying it. However my question was not about whether the US federal government can legitimately and automatically put its publications into the public domain within US jurisdiction: I explicitly asked whether this had been challenged internationally i.e. in a context that didn't recognise US legislation.